# Как с помощью заданных вероятностей заменить random(вместо случайных чисел даны вероятности)

Tags: python, python-3.x

Как с помощью заданных вероятностей заменить random?(вместо случайных чисел даны вероятности) У нас даны вероятности выпадения переменных (a, b, c, d) - 0.4, 0.3, 0.3, 0 соответственно.

Пример: Т.к вероятность выпадения "а" 0,4, она будет выпадать чаще всех в цикле, "d" c вероятностью 0, вообще не должна выпадать. Как это реализовать?

```
 import random
    a = 0.4
    b = 0.3
    c = 0.3
    d = 0
    array = [a, b, c, d]
    
    for i in range(10):
        j = random.randint(0, 3)
        print(array[j])
```

Comment: random.random() - случайное число от 0 до 1.

Comment: @Интик нам не надо случайное число, у нас вероятности выпадения переменных уже даны

Answer (score 1):

```
import random
a = 0.4
b = 0.3
c = 0.3
d = 0
array = [a, b, c, d]
    
for i in range(10):
    n = random.random()
    x = 0
    for i in array:
        x += i
        if n <= x:
            print(i)
            break
```